# SAS - Proc Report headline option issue

Tags: sas, proc-report

When I run the code below, it outputs a text file where the default hyphen for the headline option is replaced by the letter F. So I get a series of Fs dispayed across my report. Any idea what could be causing this? I've never run across this before and can't find any info about it...

```
proc printto print='c:\temp\test.txt';
run;

PROC REPORT DATA=SUM_2010 HEADLINE HEADSKIP MISSING nowd;
  COLUMNS field1 field2;

  DEFINE field1 / 'NUMBER OF things' FORMAT=COMMA20.0 WIDTH=25;
  DEFINE filed2 / 'VALUE of things' FORMAT=DOLLAR28.2 WIDTH=30;
  RBREAK AFTER/SKIP SUMMARIZE DOL;
  TITLE1 "something";
  TITLE2 "something something";
  TITLE3 "more something";
  TITLE4 "YEAR: 2010";
  RUN;
quit;
```

Comment: The specific cause for this is likely that you aren't using the default SAS font, which uses some normally otherwise appearing characters like the cursive f as certain kinds of lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the `formchar` option - this affects horizontal and vertical lines in proc tabulate and proc report.  This should provide more appealing output => `options formchar="|----||---|-/\<>*";` (run it before the proc report).